A butterfly effect of a dinosaur hunt
I read this short story at least 30 years ago, but it might be much older. I don't remember where, but probably in a collection.
This is a "paradoxical" time-travel story. A company uses time travel to bring hunters to the time of the dinosaurs. They take great precautions not to change the world history between the hunt and the present. They choose dinosaurs that are about to die anyway. They also install low pedestrian bridges (in prehistory !) over the ground to keep the hunters from setting foot on the soil, to avoid bringing back anything. (To me it is not clear how building those bridges puts less risk on the world history, especially since they will have to remove them at some point but.... well, I did not write this story !). With each group of hunters there is a guide who checks they respect the rules.
Alas, one of the hunters is so terrified at the arrival of the T-Rex which is the supposed victim that he runs away and steps outside the bridge, with the result of getting mud on his boots.
The guide is furious, but they all come back to the present.
It is immediately obvious to the guide that the present has changed, and not for the better. He looks closer to the boot of the hunter and finds a small butterfly. IIRC, he is so enraged that he kills the hunter.
Now whether the story was written after the expression "butterfly effect" was coined, in 1972 I believe, and deliberately used a butterfly as source of the problem, or if it is a coincidence, I don't know.  Conversely, were the story written before 1972, I don't believe Edward Norton Lorenz knew about this story when he chose the butterfly to illustrate his point, but anything is possible !

What's the question?

@Gae.S.  The question is  : what story has a butterfly...

@JohnRennie I made this one the dupe target because Alfred described the story much better.

I wouldn't be surprised if Lorenz was aware of A Sound of Thunder. Many scientists enjoy sci-fi, and it was a fairly well-known story. Bradbury was an influential writer, whose stories were often published in more mainstream magazines, not just the usual sci-fi "pulp" magazines.

@PM2Ring Well, now that I know that the story was written 20 years before Lorenz created the expression "butterfly effect", I do agree with you, it would make sense if he had been influenced by it !

For extra irony, the OP could have gone to the Wikipedia entry for "butterfly effect" and found a reference to the story!

I think Lorenz coined the term "butterfly effect" based on the shape of the Lorenz attractor.

Isn't it just that arbitrarily small changes in initial conditions ("the flapping of the wings of a butterly") can lead to very large divergence in a system's state if one waits "long enough" (wbut with "long enough" being but much less than "infinitely long")? So for example depending on an asteroid passing by, Pluto could be on the other side of the solar system than expected after 1 million years.

I remember this story too, but I wouldn't have remembered enough about it to even ask the question.  Thank you!

@DavidConrad the evolution of the phrase appears to be it was a sea gull flapping its wings in a 1963 publication. The 1972 change to butterfly seems to be purely to make the wings smaller. I'd speculate when computer graphics were able to plot a Lorentz attractor the visual coincidence would be obvious in time for the 1987 book by James Gleick that popularized Chaos and fractals.

As for why the walkways--my take on that is that they were carefully placed by people who knew what they were doing.

@lucasbachmann Yes, I had that book. :)

"A Sound of Thunder" by Ray Bradbury, first published in the June 28, 1952 edition of Collier's magazine.
From Wikipedia:

In the year 2055, time travel has become a practical reality, and the company Time Safari Inc. offers wealthy adventurers the chance to travel back in time to hunt extinct species such as dinosaurs. A hunter named Eckels pays $10,000 to join a hunting party that will travel back 65 million years to the Late Cretaceous period, on a guided safari to kill a Tyrannosaurus rex. As the party waits to depart, they discuss the recent presidential elections in which a far-right candidate, Deutscher, has been defeated by his opponent Keith, to the relief of many concerned.
When the party arrives in the past, Travis, the hunting guide, and his assistant warn Eckels and the two other hunters about the necessity of minimizing the events they change before they go back, since even the smallest alterations to the distant past could snowball into catastrophic changes in history. Travis explains that the hunters are obliged to stay on a levitating path to avoid disrupting the environment, any deviation will be punished with hefty fines and prosecution, Time Safari scouts had been sent back to select and tag prey whose death will have minimal effect on the future prior to the hunt, and the time machine "steps aside" to prevent people from encountering themselves in the past.
Although Eckels is initially excited about the hunt, when the monstrous Tyrannosaurus approaches, he loses his nerve. Travis tells him to go back to the time machine, but Eckels panics, steps off the path, and stumbles into the forest. The other four shoot and kill the dinosaur and see that Eckels has found his way back to the time machine. Travis threatens to leave him in the past before ordering him to remove the bullets from the dinosaur's body, as they cannot be left behind.
Upon returning to 2055, Eckels and the rest of the party notice major changes; English words are now spelled phonetically, and worst of all, Deutscher has won the election to the approval of the pro-fascist populace. Looking at the mud on his boots, Eckels finds a crushed golden butterfly, whose death has apparently changed the nature of the alternative present to which the safari has returned. He frantically pleads to undo the damage, and the story ends on a gunshot fired by Travis.

You can read the full story at the Internet Archive.
